# Not able to fetch the value outside forEach, Getting the error as Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am facing very weird error with Javascript, Can you please help me here

When I try to access the value within the forEach loop my value is printing in the console but when I try to access the value outside the loop is not working.

If I try to access the value outside the forEach I am getting error as `Cannot read property 'executionSummary' of undefined`

I have attached the screenshot as well

Java Script

```
 function arrageValues() {
        return getTheLiveDayUpdates().then(function (items) {

            var TotalCount = 0;
            var PassCount = 0;
            var FailCount = 0;
            var WIPCount = 0;
            var Unexecuted = 0;
            var msoName;
            var msoArray = [];

            items.forEach(function (item) {
                var itemtoArray = _(item).toArray();
                //console.log(item);
                itemtoArray.forEach(function (eachValue) {
                    var eachvalueToArray = _(eachValue).toArray();
                    var msoName = eachvalueToArray[5];
                    Unexecuted = Unexecuted + eachvalueToArray[18]['executionSummary'][0].count;
                    PassCount = PassCount + eachvalueToArray[18]['executionSummary'][1].count;
                    FailCount = FailCount + eachvalueToArray[18]['executionSummary'][2].count;
                    WIPCount = WIPCount + eachvalueToArray[18]['executionSummary'][3].count;
                    TotalCount = TotalCount + eachvalueToArray[0];
                    console.log("Inside", Unexecuted);
                });
                console.log("Outside", Unexecuted);
            });

        });
    }
```

[JSON](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsa4z21y/)

[image: **Console Logs**]

Comment: the error comes from within the inner loop, not outside it ... one of the "items" in the array that is in the array is undefined at index 18

Comment: What do you mean by "*when accessing the value outside the loop it is working*"?

Comment: an example of what `items` is would help (looks like a three dimensional array?) does each second level array have at least 19 items?

Comment: I have created the JSON Data in fiddle [JSON]=(https://jsfiddle.net/Lsa4z21y/)

Comment: But I am getting the values with `console.log("Inside", Unexecuted)` hence I assume it works inside forEach loop

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you help whats wrong there

Comment: not without the data

Comment: @JaromandaX I have updated the fiddle with JSON [Link]=(https://jsfiddle.net/Lsa4z21y/)

Comment: @JaromandaX I have understood the problem the last element of the array is having the object name with `recordsCount` I think this is causing the problem, How to avoid this issue